# Capturing MouseEnter event in a Tab [Javafx]

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I would like to be able to capture the MOUSEENTER event when hovering over a tab.

I have tried to do it from the Graphic of the tab, which is not the optimal solution, but it is a Node object with such events.

This is what I wrote:

```
tab.getGraphic().setOnMouseEntered((MouseEvent event) -> {
             System.out.println("..... mouse entered");
             //...
         });
```

This solution does not error but is ignored by Javafx,   any way to do this?

**UPDATE**:  The way to create the tab and add its graphic, is like the following excerpt.  The tab itself works fine and the graphic displays fine.

```
     Tab tab = addChatTab(root, strName, strID, chat, false);
     // setup tab graphic  
     switch (win.type) {
         case wtChat:
            if (chat !=null)
                if (chat.isPublic()) {
                    tab.setGraphic(new ImageView(Main.me.imgTabPublic));

                 } else {
                    if (chat.isDCC())  
                         tab.setGraphic(new ImageView(Main.me.imgTabDCC)); 
                    else tab.setGraphic(new ImageView(Main.me.imgTabPrivate));
             } 

            break;
         case wtWall:
            tab.setGraphic(new ImageView(Main.me.imgTabWall));
            break;
         case wtMessage:
            tab.setGraphic(new ImageView(Main.me.imgTabMessage));
            break;
     }
```

Comment: Did you set a graphic on the tab?

Comment: Yes, of course, if you don't you get a null pointer exception when you try to set the even or add a listener.

Comment: Can you show how you set up the tan and it's graphic? This worked fine for me.

Comment: See the updated question with the info you requested.  I must note that the tab itself is working fine.

Comment: It's really hard to answer a question unless you post enough information to help figure out what you are doing that's relevant. You should always create and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for questions like this. See if the answer helps: otherwise create an example from scratch that others can run and that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a mouse handler on a graphic, then the handler will only be invoked when the mouse interacts with the graphic itself. In this example, the first tab has both text and a graphic set, so the mouse handler is not invoked when the mouse moves onto the text. The second tab sets no text but uses a label as the graphic, with the label containing the text. In that case the mouse handler is invoked when the mouse moves onto the text or image.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TabPaneHoverTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // hover only applies on graphic:
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
        tab1.setGraphic(new Rectangle(16, 16, Color.RED));

        // Tab only uses graphic (no text),
        // so hover appears to apply to whole tab:
        Tab tab2 = new Tab();
        Label tab2Graphic = new Label("Tab 2", new Rectangle(16, 16, Color.GREEN));
        tab2.setGraphic(tab2Graphic);

        tab1.getGraphic().setOnMouseEntered(e -> System.out.println("Hover on tab 1"));
        tab2.getGraphic().setOnMouseEntered(e -> System.out.println("Hover on tab 2"));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(new TabPane(tab1, tab2));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you James_D,  your example works.  I modified it to change the Label graphic for an ImageView... and as in my case, it stopped working.

I guess the workaround is to make the graphic a Label and place the Imageview as its graphic.  Should not be neccesary, but it is doable.